# Powershell: Get all the available Drive letters

Tags: powershell, regex-negation

Using Powershell I am seeking the inverse of the drive letters currently in use.

The following code In a .bat-file reveals the currently available drives.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
net use
SET DRVLST=
FOR %%p IN (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO if not exist %%p:\nul @set DRVLST=!DRVLST! %%p:
echo Available Drives: %DRVLST%
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
net view %SERVERNAME%
ENDLOCAL
```

In Powershell the drive letters in use can be extracted and stored in a variable *$drives_in_use* for further processing.

```
$drives_in_use=(Get-PSDrive).Name -match '^[a-z]$'
write-host $drives_in_use
```

How to obtain the result to be the 'subtraction' of *$drives_in_use* from all drives A to Z?

```
$availableDrives = $allDrives - $drives_in_use
```

I would assume that a reverse-lookup regex might be the solution. But I don't know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use .Net like:

```
$availableDrives = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' -split '' | Where-Object { $_ -notin ([System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives().Name).Substring(0,1) }
```

or

```
$availableDrives = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.ToCharArray() | Where-Object { $_ -notin ([System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives().Name).Substring(0,1) }
```

or

```
$availableDrives = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' -split '' | Where-Object { $_ -notin [System.IO.Directory]::GetLogicalDrives().Substring(0,1) }
```

or use `Get-CimInstance` (slower)

```
$availableDrives = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' -split '' | Where-Object { $_ -notin (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_logicaldisk).DeviceID.Substring(0,1) }
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create an alphabet array and filter with the `notcontains` operator.

```
#Create alphabet array (https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html)
$alph = 65..90 | ForEach-Object {[char]$_}
$availableDrives = $alph | Where-Object { $drives_in_use -notcontains $_ }
```

If you're using PowerShell 6+ then you can create $alph like this

```
$alph = 'A'..'Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using the [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) cmdlet:

```bash
Compare-Object -PassThru (Get-PsDrive [A-Z]).Name ([char[]] 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
```

In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, which now supports `[char]` instances as the endpoints of `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-),
you can simplifiy to:

```bash
Compare-Object -PassThru (Get-PsDrive [A-Z]).Name ('A'..'Z')
```

- `Compare-Object` only reports *differences* between the two collections by default, and in this case the first collection - all currently defined drives whose name is a single letter between `A` and `Z` - is by definition as subset of the second collection. Therefore, the result is those letters in the second collection that aren't present in the first collection, i.e. the unused drive letters.
- `-PassThru` ensures that the differing objects are output as-is,<sup>[1]</sup> instead of the default behavior of being reported as the `.InputObject` property of  `[pscustomobject]` wrappers, alongside a `.SideIndicator` property that signals what collection the object came from (`'<='` indicating an object from the first collection, `'=>'` from the second).

---

<sup>[1] They are, however, *decorated* with an [ETS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) `.SideIndicator` property.</sup>